# convert xml attribute (which is a hash) to a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a node that looks like this, in the xml file:

```
<property name="nameA" value="{ "keyA": "valueA", "keyB": "valueB" }"/>
```

I create the nokogiri object, search it for the value of that node, and get this:

```
{ "keyA": "valueA", "keyB": "valueB" }
```

I need to modify valueA.  Do I convert this to a Ruby hash, modify it, and then convert it back?  How would I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like JSON.

```
gem install json
```

Then:

```
require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse('{ "keyA": "valueA", "keyB": "valueB" }')
hash['keyC'] = 'valueC';
attr = hash.to_json
```